# iOS Firebase ML Kit Simple Audio Recognition "Failed to create a TFLite interpreter for the given model"

Tags: python, ios, firebase, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit

I have been trying to implement the [Simple Audio Recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) Tensorflow sample in iOS using the [Firebase's ML kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/use-custom-models?authuser=0). I have successfully trained the model and converted it into a TFlite file. The model takes the Audio(wav) file path as input([String]) and gives the predictions as output(float32). My iOS code is fairly simple

```
func initMLModel(){

        /*Initializing local TFLite model*/
        guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "converted_model", ofType: "tflite") else {
            return
        }

        let myLocalModel = LocalModelSource.init(modelName: "My", path: modelPath)
        let registrationSuccessful = ModelManager.modelManager().register(myLocalModel)

        let options = ModelOptions(cloudModelName: nil, localModelName: "My")

        let interpreter = ModelInterpreter.modelInterpreter(options: options)

        let ioOptions = ModelInputOutputOptions()
        do {
            try ioOptions.setInputFormat(index: 0, type: .unknown, dimensions: []) /*input is string path. Since string is not defined, setting it as unknown.*/
            try ioOptions.setOutputFormat(index: 0, type: .float32, dimensions: [1,38]) /* output is 1 of 38 labelled classes*/
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to set IO \(error.debugDescription)")
        }

        let inputs = ModelInputs()
        var audioData = Data()

        let audiopath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio", ofType: "wav")
        do {
            audioData = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: audiopath!))
            //try inputs.addInput(audioData) /*If the input type is direct audio data*/
            try inputs.addInput([audiopath])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Cannot get audio file data \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }

        interpreter.run(inputs: inputs, options: ioOptions) { (outputs, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error running the model \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }
            do {
                let output = try outputs!.output(index: 0) as? [[NSNumber]]
                let probabilities = output?[0]

                guard let labelsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "conv_labels", ofType: "txt") else { return }
                let fileContents = try? String.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: labelsPath))
                guard let labels = fileContents?.components(separatedBy: "\n") else {return}

                for i in 0 ..< labels.count {
                    if let probability = probabilities?[i] {
                        print("\(labels[i]) : \(probability)")
                    }
                }

            }catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error in parsing the Output \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

But when i run this i get the following error output `Failed to create a TFLite interpreter for the given model`. The Complete Log of the sample app is as below

```
    2019-01-07 18:22:31.447917+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515789]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
    2019-01-07 18:22:33.354449+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515686] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
    2019-01-07 18:22:34.789665+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515812] 5.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50400000 started
    2019-01-07 18:22:34.790814+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515812] 5.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
    2019-01-07 18:22:35.542993+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515823] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7f9db0701d70] get output frames failed, state 8196
    2019-01-07 18:22:35.543205+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515823] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7f9db0701d70] get output frames failed, state 8196
    2019-01-07 18:22:35.543923+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515823] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
    2019-01-07 18:22:35.544070+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515823] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
    2019-01-07 18:22:39.981492+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515823] 5.15.0 - [Firebase/MLKit][I-MLK002000] ModelInterpreterErrorReporter: Didn't find custom op for name 'DecodeWav' with version 1
    2019-01-07 18:22:39.981686+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515823] 5.15.0 - [Firebase/MLKit][I-MLK002000] ModelInterpreterErrorReporter: Registration failed.
    Failed to set IO Error Domain=com.firebase.ml Code=3 "input format 0 has invalid nil or empty dimensions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=input format 0 has invalid nil or empty dimensions.}
    2019-01-07 18:22:40.604961+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515812] 5.15.0 - [Firebase/MLKit][I-MLK002000] ModelInterpreterErrorReporter: Didn't find custom op for name 'DecodeWav' with version 1
    2019-01-07 18:22:40.605199+0530 sample_core_ML[67500:3515812] 5.15.0 - [Firebase/MLKit][I-MLK002000] ModelInterpreterErrorReporter: Registration failed.
    Error running the model Optional(Error Domain=com.firebase.ml Code=2 "Failed to create a TFLite interpreter for the given model (/Users/minimaci73/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7FE413C1-3820-496A-B0CE-033BE2F3212A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/868CB2FE-77D8-4B1F-8853-C2E17ECA63F2/sample_core_ML.app/converted_model.tflite)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create a TFLite interpreter for the given model (/Users/minimaci73/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7FE413C1-3820-496A-B0CE-033BE2F3212A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/868CB2FE-77D8-4B1F-8853-C2E17ECA63F2/sample_core_ML.app/converted_model.tflite).})
```

When looked at this line `Didn't find custom op for name 'DecodeWav'` I looked up on the custom supported ops and found that Tensorflow already supports this in the [audio_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/audio_ops.cc) by default.

**Details**

My Tensorflow Version : 1.12.0

Environment : Conda

OS Version : Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.2

Deployment target : ios 12.0

Installation type : Pod Installation (pod 'Firebase/MLModelInterpreter')

But i ran my training model first in v1.9.0. Then updated the Tensorflow to latest v1.12.0 to run the TFLite Convertor. Both are master branch.

**My TFLite Convertor code Python**

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph_def_file = "my_frozen_graph.pb"
input_arrays = ["wav_data"]
output_arrays = ["labels_softmax"]
input_shape = {"wav_data" : [1,99,40,1]}

converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays, input_shape)
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same question in the firebase quickstart iOS repository, And i got the following response [DecodeWav op is never supported by TensorFlowLite](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/614#issuecomment-453218055). So at present Tensorflow Lite does not support audio processing even-though Tensorflow itself supports audio processing.